# How to get the swiping edge in flutter using flutter_swipe_cards

Tags: flutter, dart

I can't find out how to find the current swiping edge of the card swiper.

Flutter code:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

class ExampleMatch extends StatefulWidget {
    const ExampleMatch({ super.key });

    @override
    _ExampleMatchState createState() => _ExampleMatchState();
}

class _ExampleMatchState extends State<JobMatch> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
    bool _onSwipe(
        int previousIndex,
        int? currentIndex,
        CardSwiperDirection direction,
    ) {
        setState(() { currentSDIndex = currentIndex ?? 0; });

        String status = '';

        switch (direction) {
            case CardSwiperDirection.bottom:
                status = 'dumped';

                setState(() {
                    buttonSize = bottomButtonSize;
                    swipeDirectionText = 'Dumped';
                });
                break;

            case CardSwiperDirection.left:
                status = 'not-matched';

                setState(() {
                    buttonSize = leftRightButtonSize;
                    swipeDirectionText = 'Discarded';
                });
                break;

            case CardSwiperDirection.right:
                status = 'match';

                setState(() {
                    buttonSize = leftRightButtonSize;
                    swipeDirectionText = 'Liked';
                });
                break;

            case CardSwiperDirection.top:
                status = 'super-match';

                setState(() {
                    buttonSize = topButtonSize;
                    swipeDirectionText = 'Super Liked';
                });
                break;

            case CardSwiperDirection.none:
                setState(() {
                    buttonSize = topButtonSize;
                    swipeDirectionText = 'none';
                });
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    void _onSwipeDirectionChange(CardSwiperDirection horizontalDirection, CardSwiperDirection verticalDirection) {
        String? swipeText;

        // sort of didn't match
        if (horizontalDirection == CardSwiperDirection.left && verticalDirection == CardSwiperDirection.top) {
            setState(() {
                swipeText = 'sort of did not match';
            });
        }
        // strongly didn't match
        else if (horizontalDirection == CardSwiperDirection.left && verticalDirection == CardSwiperDirection.bottom) {
            setState(() {
                swipeText = 'strongly of did not match';
            });
        }
        // strongly matched
        else if (horizontalDirection == CardSwiperDirection.right && verticalDirection == CardSwiperDirection.top) {
            setState(() {
                swipeText = 'strongly matched';
            });
        }
        // sort of matched
        else if (horizontalDirection == CardSwiperDirection.right && verticalDirection == CardSwiperDirection.bottom) {
            setState(() {
                swipeText = 'sort of matched';
            });
        }
        // sort of super matched
        else if (verticalDirection == CardSwiperDirection.top && horizontalDirection == CardSwiperDirection.left) {
            setState(() {
                swipeText = 'sort of super matched';
            });
        }
        // strongly of super matched
        else if (verticalDirection == CardSwiperDirection.top && horizontalDirection == CardSwiperDirection.right) {
            setState(() {
                swipeText = 'strongly of super matched';
            });
        }
        // sort of dumped
        else if (verticalDirection == CardSwiperDirection.bottom && horizontalDirection == CardSwiperDirection.left) {
            setState(() {
                swipeText = 'sort of dumped';
            });
        }
        // strongly of dumped
        else if (verticalDirection == CardSwiperDirection.bottom && horizontalDirection == CardSwiperDirection.right) {
            setState(() {
                swipeText = 'strongly dumped';
            });
        }

        if (swipeText != null) {
            setState(() {
                swipeDirectionText = swipeText!;
            });
        }
    }

    Widget getSwipeCards(BuildContext context) {
        double offset = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 100) * 7;

        return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 87, top: 15),
            child: CardSwiper(
                controller: controller,
                cardsCount: cards.length,
                isDisabled: currentSDIndex == cards.length - 1,
                isLoop: false,
                maxAngle: 60,
                onSwipe: _onSwipe,
                onUndo: _onUndo,
                numberOfCardsDisplayed: 3,
                backCardOffset: Offset(offset, offset),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 24, left: 24, right: 24, bottom: 10),
                cardBuilder: (
                    context,
                    index,
                    horizontalThresholdPercentage,
                    verticalThresholdPercentage,
                ) => cards[index],
                onSwipeDirectionChange: _onSwipeDirectionChange,
            )
        );
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
            color: FitnessAppTheme.background,
            child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                body: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                        getSwipeCards(context)
                    ],
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

The drag directions and hot points on each edge are as follows:

- left->top = sort of did not match
- left->bottom = strongly did not match
- top->left = sort of super matched
- top->right = strongly super matched
- right->top = strongly matched
- right->bottom = sort of matched
- bottom->left = sort of dumped
- bottom->right = strongly dumped

How can I achieve this?